# How to open a link in a new tab?

Tags: php, forms, url, drupal, drupal-modules

I created a custom module for Drupal 8

I want my link to open in a new tab, but it does not work.

Yet I added `['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']]`

Why does not it work ?

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\commerce_agree_cgv\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane;

use Drupal\Core\Form\FormStateInterface;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneBase;
use Drupal\commerce_checkout\Plugin\Commerce\CheckoutPane\CheckoutPaneInterface;
use Drupal\Core\Link;
use Drupal\Core\Url;

/**
 * Provides the completion message pane.
 *
 * @CommerceCheckoutPane(
 *   id = "agree_cgv",
 *   label = @Translation("Agree CGV"),
 *   default_step = "review",
 * )
 */
class AgreeCGV extends CheckoutPaneBase implements CheckoutPaneInterface {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function buildPaneForm(array $pane_form, FormStateInterface $form_state, array &$complete_form) {
    $pane_form['cgv'] = [
      '#type' => 'checkbox',
      '#default_value' => FALSE,
      '#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept <a href="@cgv">the general terms and conditions of business</a>.', ['@cgv' => Url::fromRoute('entity.commerce_store.canonical', ['commerce_store' => 3], ['attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']])->toString()]),
      '#required' => TRUE,
      '#weight' => $this->getWeight(),
    ];
    return $pane_form;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi, I don't know what the attributes in your PHP code are for, but I think you can achieve what you want by replacing `<a href="@cgv">` by `<a href="@cgv" target="_blank">`. Since the opening of the link is in relation with HTML and has nothing to do with PHP.

Comment: @ankabout Thank you, it works. I thought it needed a special code for php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its normal URL::fromRoute return path, not link
you have 2 solution her:

1 - use [Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core!lib!Drupal!Core!Link.php/function/Link%3A%3AcreateFromRoute/8.2.x)

```
$options = ['absolute' => TRUE, 'attributes' => ['target' => '_blank']];
$link_object = Drupal\Core\Link::createFromRoute(t('the general terms and conditions of business'),
    'entity.node.canonical', ['node' => "123"],
    $options);
$link = $link_object->toString();
```

and the result : `<a href="http://exemple.dev/en/node/123" target="_blank">the general terms and conditions of business</a>`

or

2 - use [URL](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Url.php/function/Url%3A%3AfromRoute/8.2.x)

```
'#title' => $this->t('I have read and accept <a href="@cgv" target="_blank">the general terms and conditions of business</a>.', ['@cgv' => Url::fromRoute('entity.commerce_store.canonical', ['commerce_store' => 3], ['absolute' => true])->toString()]),
```

i hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, how to add at the end of my link `/cgv` ?